# How to use Select2 ajax call to bring data from a function into a <select> field?

Tags: php, yii, jquery-select2

My function is

```
public function actionGetMy() {
        [
            {
                color: "red",
                value: "#f00"
            },
            {
                color: "green",
                value: "#0f0"
            },
            {
                color: "blue",
                value: "#00f"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Now how should I write select2 query to bring data into the  field. The select field is

```
<select name="My[]" multiple id="my">
```

Comment: you want multiselect..?

Comment: no a normal select will do.

Comment: hey show your view code also . Your question is not clear . Do you have two select dropdowns or only one?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ajax like that

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#my').select2({
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    ajax: {
      url: "optionlist.php",
      dataType: 'json',
      data: function (term, page) {
        return {
          q: term
        };
      },
      results: function (data, page) {
        return { results: data };
      }
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you want like

```
<select name="My" id="my"> 
<?php
foreach($colors as  $value){
?>
   <option value="<?php echo $value['value']; ?>"> <?php echo $value['color']; ?> </option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: i wan to use select2 ajax.

Comment: you want color name from select1 and value from select2

Comment: yes..or you can only show me colr name from select1 only

Comment: i dont understand why you want to use two select box when it can work by using single select box..

Comment: ok...then can u please show me how to do it with a single select box.

Comment: first tell me you want create date like in actionGetMy() from select ?

Comment: u can show me by taking a json array or object in actionGetMy(). and if u want you can use input type=text in place of select.